# compositions of $n $ into odd parts

Tags: combinatorics

Find the number of compositions of n into odd parts.

attempt: Recall a composition of n is of n is a way of expressing n as an ordered sum of positive integers, called the parts of the composition.
Then we know that for all positive integers $n$ and $k$, the number of compositions of $n$ into $k$ parts is $n-1 \choose k-1$. And for all positive numbers  $n$ , the number of all compositions of $n$ is $2^{n-1} $=$ \Sigma_{k=1}^n$ $n-1 \choose k-1$. I don't really know how to approach this problem.

could someone please provide some feedback? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that 
$$x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_k = n \tag{1}$$
where $x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_k$  are odd positive integers.  Then for $1 \leq j \leq k$, we can write $x_j = 2y_j + 1$, where $y_j$ is a nonnegative integer.  Substitution into equation 1 yields
\begin{align*}
2y_1 + 1 + 2y_2 + 1 + \cdots + 2y_k + 1 & = n\\
2y_1 + 2y_2 + \cdots + 2y_k & = n - k
\end{align*}
If $n - k$ is an odd integer, such a composition is not possible.  On the other hand, if $n - k$ is an even integer, then 
$$y_1 + y_2 + \cdots + y_k = \frac{n - k}{2} \tag{2}$$
is an equation in the nonnegative integers.  A particular solution of equation 2 corresponds to the placement of $k - 1$ addition signs in a row of $(n - k)/2$ ones.  Thus, the number of possible compositions of $n$ into odd parts is 
$$\binom{\frac{n - k}{2} + k - 1}{k - 1} = \binom{\frac{n + k - 2}{2}}{k - 1} $$
since we must choose which $k - 1$ of the $(n + k - 2)/2$ symbols ($(n - k)/2$ ones and $k - 1$ addition signs) will be addition signs.

Comment: So we must have $n-k$ to be an even number for equation (2) to have a solution? And I see the $k-1$ addition signs, but what do you mean with a row of $(n-k)/2$ ones?

Comment: Yes.  Notice that if $n - k$ is odd, then we have an even integer equal to an odd integer in the equation that precedes equation 2.  Suppose $n = 21$ and $k = 5$.  Then $n - k = 16$, so $(n - k)/2 = 8$.  We can represent the solution $y_1 = 2$, $y_2 = 3$, $y_3 = 0$, $y_4 = 2$, $y_5 = 1$ ($x_1 = 5$, $x_2 = 7$, $x_3 = 1$, $x_4 = 5$, $x_5 = 3$) by placing four addition signs in a row of eight ones as follows:  $$1 1 + 1 1 1 + + 1 1 + 1$$  More generally, any solution of the equation $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 = 8$ corresponds to the placement of four addition signs in a row of eight ones.

Comment: So we are kind of adding the 1s on $11 + 111+ 11 + 1$ so we get our solution $8$?

Comment: I am expressing $8$ in the form of eight ones.  A particular solution corresponds to the placement of the addition signs.  $$11 + 111 + + 11 + 1$$ corresponds to the solution $y_1 = 2$, $y_2 = 3$, $y_3 = 0$, $y+4 = 2$, $y_5 = 1$, while $$1 + 1 + 1 + 1 1 1  + 1 1$$ corresponds to the solution $y_1 = 1$, $y_2 = 1$, $y_3 = 1$, $y_4 = 3$, $y_5 = 2$.  The total number of solutions of the equation $$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 = 8$$ is the nonnegative integers is $$\binom{8 + 4}{4} = \binom{12}{4}$$ since we must choose which four of the twelve symbols (4 + signs, 8 ones) will be addition signs.